# problems with LINQ method not returning any results

Tags: c#, list, linq, asp.net-core-mvc, ienumerable

Currently my LINQ Query into my list is not returning search results. I am attempting to pass the method a string, where it searches through each objects `FirstName, LastName, and Username` fields.
Here is my method:

```
        public IEnumerable<Volunteer> Search(string key)
        {
            IEnumerable<Volunteer> searchResults = _volunteerList.Where(v => v.FirstName == key 
                                                                        || v.LastName == key 
                                                                        || v.Username == key);

            return searchResults;
        }
```

I have verified that the string `key` is being passed into the method, and is holding the correct value "Bob".

here is a list of objects in my `_volunteerList`:

```
                new Volunteer {id = 1, FirstName = "Bob", LastName = "Evans", Username = "BEvans", Password= "1991", StreetAddress = "1995 StreetName Ave", State = "FL", City = "Jacksonville", ZipCode = 32225, ApprovalStatus = "Approved"},
                new Volunteer {id = 2, FirstName = "Jim", LastName = "Evans", Username = "JEvans", Password= "1992", StreetAddress = "1995 StreetName Ave", State = "FL", City = "Jacksonville", ZipCode = 32225, ApprovalStatus = "Approved"}
```

To me from everything I have looked up the syntax for the LINQ statement looks correct, and is not returning any errors (in VS19 at least). Is there something about this that I am missing?

Thanks in Advance.

**FYI**: Relevant methods/code:

**Homecontroller - Search()**

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Search(string key)
        {

            IEnumerable<Volunteer> results = _volunteerRepository.Search(key);

            ViewData.Model = results;
            return View("SearchResults");
        }
```

**ManageVolunteers (View) - Form**

```
<form method="get" asp-action="Search" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="Key" value ="Bob" class="form-control"/> </td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Is it showing the expected value of key when you put breakpoint and debug?

Comment: Unable to reproduce. The only thing that comes to mind is a difference in case. "bob" vs "Bob" The == comparison is case sensitive.

Comment: Just like @Steve, I am unable to reproduce. I had the same though about case sensitivity. The other thing to check is if _volunteerList has any value to start with before doing the where statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to be frank... I dont know what I did, but now the correct output is showing on my SearchResults view.

All is correct. I dont know why but after a couple hours of working on this prior to uploading the results list is showing up correctly.

I appreciate the attempted help.

Comment: you should accept your answer (click the checkbox on the left of this answer)

Comment: I planned to.. but cant accept my own answer for 2 days according to the stackoverflow website

Comment: oh yeah i forgot :)

Comment: Because this question and relative answer are not something that can be reproduced in any way, the best path is to delete the question. No future readers can find any value here. See https://xkcd.com/979/

Answer (score 0):

you have declared `_volunteerList` as `List<Volunteer>` or `IEnumerable<Volunteer>` ? Some type conversion issue is there it seems. Try keeping `List<Volunteer>` wherever `IEnumerable<Volunteer>` is used. See if that works.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem recently, what I did was put it at the end of my IEnumerable. a ToList ();

```
IEnumerable<Volunteer> searchResults = _volunteerList.Where(v => v.FirstName == key 
                                                                        || v.LastName == key 
                                                                        || v.Username == key).ToList();
```

Comment: This just converts the results to a List. It doesn't fix anything.

Comment: As @Andy mentioned converting to list does nothing if iinq query returns no results. Casting to list would give different benefits, e.g. make it possible to make changes to a collection (IEnumerable is read-only, with lower overal overhead), but that is not what the question asks.

Comment: @VytautasPlečkaitis -- sure I get how lists work. But simply converting a collection to a List isn't going to magically make items appear, which is what i was trying to convey.

Comment: @Andy I totally agree, the comment was meant for Otavio.